# Using built-in pandas frequencies to simulate semiannual frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas time series indexed with a `DatetimeIndex`, and I need to have support for semiannual frequencies. The basic semiannual frequency has `1H=Jan-Jun` and `2H=Jul-Dec`, though some series might have the last month be a month other than December, for instance `1H=Dec-May` and `2H=Jun-Nov`.

I imagine I could certainly achieve what I want by making a custom class that derives from pandas' `DateOffset` class. However, before I go and do that, I'm curious if there is a way I can simply use a built-in frequency, for instance a 6-month frequency? I have tried to do this, but cannot get resampling to the way I want.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = np.arange(12)
s = pd.Series(data, pd.date_range(start=datetime(2007,1,31), periods=len(data), freq="M"))
s.resample("6M")

Out[11]:
2007-01-31    0.0
2007-07-31    3.5
2008-01-31    9.0
Freq: 6M
```

Notice how pandas is aggregating using windows from Aug-Jan and Feb-Jul. In this base case I would want Jan-Jun and Jul-Dec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of the two `Series.resample()` parameters `loffset=` and `closed=`.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np, pandas as pd

In [2]: data = np.arange(1, 13)

In [3]: s = pd.Series(data, pd.date_range(start='1/31/2007', periods=len(data), freq='M'))

In [4]: s.resample('6M', how='sum', closed='left', loffset='-1M')
Out[4]: 
2007-06-30    21
2007-12-31    57
```

I used `loffset='-1M'` to tell pandas to aggregate one period earlier than its default (moved us to Jan-Jun).

I used `closed='left'` to make the aggregator include the 'left' end of the sample window and exclude the 'right' end (`closed='right'` is the default behavior).

NOTE: I used `how='sum'` just to make sure it was doing what I thought. You can use any of the appropriate `how`'s.

Comment: Thanks, this is a reasonable answer. I do notice a couple issues though. First, if we move the start date to end of February, we need to make loffset='-2M'. Second, if we were disaggregating instead of aggregating (say the original series was "A"), then we need to take out loffset. This probably necessitates a wrapper function to handle the resampling if we want to make this generic (so the user doesn't have to worry about the dates or whether we are upsampling or downsampling). I'm happy to accept the answer though if there are no cleaner solutions.

Comment: I agree with what you said about having data starting in Feb. would require `loffset=-'2M'`. The user would just have to understand their data well enough to know what how to set that. I am not sure I understand your second point. You said 'say the original series was "A"'. I don't know what "A" is. Can you clarify?

Comment: I meant if the original series was annual frequency (`freq="A"`)

Comment: Oh ok thanks that is clear now. I see what you are saying. I am not sure of an elegant way to do it without having some wrapper function. I haven't seen what you are describing as a built-in pandas function yet.